# Does DSL or Java Fluent API design effect the Application performance?

Tags: java, dsl, fluent

Is there decrease in application performance if I design application with either using internal DSL(Domain specific Language) or external DSL(Domain specific Language) or fluent API design patterns?

Comment: It depends on what the alternative would have been... you could write code without these that is less or more performant...

Comment: External DSL will require a parsing phase so it's slower than Internal DSL which is often implemented using Fluent API.

Comment: Is that means no change(small change) in performance if design application with these patterns?

Comment: @zafarkhaja what about others, in case of internal dsl we need create more object than without using internal dsl.

Comment: @user2613486 in case of Internal DSL it might require more classes and methods but compared to the parsing phase the overhead is negligible.

Comment: @zafarkhaja: If the work done by the DSL is trivial, your observation is correct.  Otherwise, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

External DSLs can lead to far better performance, and usability, than internal DSLs.

The purpose of a DSL is to let an engineer specify a problem or solution succinctly and clearly, so he is able solve that problem more quickly and effectively.

To the extent the problem has no need for high performance, one can build an internal DSL out of a set of subroutines and simply call them to achieve the desired effect.  It is reasonable to note that most computations are not expensive, thus the standard warning about "premature optimization".

However, many DSLs *do* need high performance (SQL, expert systems,  lexer and parser generators).  These solutions often require sophisticated algorithms (parsing, name resolution, flow analysis, boolean equation construction/simplification) to analyze the DSL specification instance provided by the engineer, and then apply special algorithms (pattern matching, FSA construction, Rete networks) perhaps along with sophisticated code generation and optimizations (query optimizations, special case handling, code motion, algebraic simplification) to produce the effective answer.  In this case, internal DSLs are IMHO pretty much a disaster, because it is very hard to reason about just the API calls without getting reasoning about the rest of the language tangled into the process.  It is also hard to find the boundaries of the DSL specification instance; where does it end, and just plain programming end?

In general, I think "external" DSLs, those with a specialized notation (be it text or graph) are simply easier to write (and then read). In some cases, one cannot in realize the DSL without the notation (consider LR parser generators or Rete networks; these are not practical to code by hand, you have to have external DSL and supporting tools).  If the purpose is to enable engineers to solve problems many times, I believe readability and expressiveness are what you should optimize, not ease of implementation.  SQL is much easier to read than any procedural pile of database table accesses.  This is a win for maintenance, too; if the DSL has any success, people will want to change what they specified. The downside to an external DSL is one must design a decent specification notation for it, and that may not be easy to do or within the skills of the domain designer, and building tools to support the DSL are often considered to be difficult. (Check my bio, I have an answer for the latter).

The only good argument for an internal DSL is that it won't be used very many times, and so it isn't worth the effort to design the corresponding specification language or supporting tools.   That makes me wonder about the actual utility of the DSL being proposed.

Answer (score 0):

***A small argument _pro_ internal DSL*** (Please downvote if this is going way too much.)

***Internal DSL***

An internal DSL construes a model, in a type-safe way, and often with semantic checks. Autocompletion helps too. So if not application performance, it is good for software quality, aka development performance.

Now a good DSL consists of builder classes, that construe a separately defined model. The final evaluation, reduction to a result, can be "compiled."

Java uses this in regular expression Pattern/Matcher, with a `Pattern.compile/matcher`. Where there is no real DSL, but also a builder of an internal regex model.

To recap, whence the model is ready built, it can be "compiled" just as well. And at some time  the hotspot compiler kicks in.

***External DSL***

But an external DSL may precompile to more immediate code, sparing the compilation and optimisation of an inner DSL. You cannot as easily follow the code, the data model, the optimizations. Some effort of the DSL must go into syntax coloring / syntax errors / autocompletion. Also the produce of the external DSL compiler might be more data than code. The "loader" part must be fast too.

***Overhead of an inner DSL:*** And what is to be considered.

The overhead is not large between a fluent API and building the model immediately. The often `return this;` for chained calls, should best be done in `final` (non-overridable) methods so the compiler might optimize immediately, instead of relying on detection of the hotspot compiler. The semantic checks are an inevitable overhead: errors are problematic as they are, no need to hide them. If they result in iterating code, the data structures you are building might be wrong (= use maps). So the overhead should be small enough.

My personal conclusion is that DSLs are beneficial for development, and sufficiently fast. Often the next step is the problematic one. jOOQ fine, JPA criteria API fine, ORM has some issues. The same with Java 8, lambdas. Seen them use as DSL, quite interesting, and there it might just be too circumstantial, overwrought.

At the moment DSLs are applied in just a couple of areas: technical interfacing like java+SQL where it is not really needed. And business logic where developers sometimes shift the responsibility to the end customer for things like programming, versioning, staging. (Changed business rules that are immediately in effect on the life system, form editors.) Efficiency of those business DSLs are a matter of having a complex semantical model behind the system, like a database engine. Inefficiencies are due to a declarative/procedural mismatch.

The **unification** of code crossing languages can partly go deep; Java + SQL: Java passing a java stored procedure to SQL. Maybe the same for vector processing.

***P.S.***

.NET has some cross/hybrid-language compiler effort (I think Irony) to yield token streams, ASTs and start from there.